# FFmpeg av_register_all() memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, ffmpeg

I made a conversion function and I started to figure out the memory leaks.I started by make a small program to figure out the leaks but for some reason av_register_all() is also getting a memory leak. Is there something that I am suppose to free?

main.cpp:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <queue>   
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

//#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {    
#ifndef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#endif
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
#include <libavutil/common.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavutil/avassert.h>
#include <libavutil/avstring.h>
#include <libavutil/frame.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h> 
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h> 
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h> 
#include <libavutil/dict.h>
}


int main (int argc, char ** argv){
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVFrame *filteredFrame;
    AVPacket pkt;

    //Initialize all codecs
    av_register_all();
}
```

Output from valgrind:

```
==31165== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31165==     in use at exit: 81 bytes in 2 blocks
==31165==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 2 frees, 167 bytes allocated
==31165== 
==31165== Searching for pointers to 2 not-freed blocks
==31165== Checked 9,196,888 bytes
==31165== 
==31165== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==31165==    at 0x4C2CC70: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31165==    by 0x6DE768F: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:141)
==31165==    by 0x6DE70C0: dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (dlopen.c:87)
==31165==    by 0x8DC7273: x265_api_get_63 (in /usr/local/lib/libx265.so.63)
==31165==    by 0x5958E74: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.56.41.100)
==31165==    by 0x59D76B1: avcodec_register_all (in /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.56.41.100)
==31165==    by 0x4E6B342: av_register_all (in /usr/local    /lib/libavformat.so.56.36.100)
==31165==    by 0x400830: main (main.cpp:39)
==31165== 
==31165== 49 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2
==31165==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31165==    by 0x400FDC0: _dl_signal_error (dl-error.c:90)
==31165==    by 0x40146CF: _dl_open (dl-open.c:715)
==31165==    by 0x6DE702A: dlopen_doit (dlopen.c:66)
==31165==    by 0x400FFF3: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:187)
==31165==    by 0x6DE762C: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:163)
==31165==    by 0x6DE70C0: dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (dlopen.c:87)
==31165==    by 0x8DC7273: x265_api_get_63 (in /usr/local/lib/libx265.so.63)
==31165==    by 0x5958E74: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.56.41.100)
==31165==    by 0x59D76B1: avcodec_register_all (in /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.56.41.100)
==31165==    by 0x4E6B342: av_register_all (in /usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.56.36.100)
==31165==    by 0x400830: main (main.cpp:39)
==31165== 
==31165== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31165==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31165==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31165==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31165==    still reachable: 81 bytes in 2 blocks
==31165==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31165== 
==31165== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==31165== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think ffmpeg is supposed to call [`x265_cleanup`](https://x265.readthedocs.org/en/default/api.html#cleanup) on exit, but it has no API interface for closing down the library, so that's why you get this issue. You could file a [bug report](https://www.ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html) about it.

Comment: Thank you! Note that the impact is rather small, it looks like you lose 81 bytes and that only happens once in the application. Even if this were to be fixed, it would only deallocate the memory on application exit, so the practical impact is really very small. Regardless, thanks for the bug report :)

Comment: That is true. I ended up making a suppression file for valgrind to suppress it. Though it would be nice if this could be fixed.